# AngularJS: How to get properties from arbitrary type?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5

I have somewhat of a complex requirement here (a real head-scratcher)... and I'm not sure on the best way to proceed:

**Requirement:**

Build a page for managing widgets (CMS content blocks) in `MVC5` using `AngularJS` for the frontend (as per the rest of the admin UI). The problem is that each widget has its own specific set of properties. They all share some properties like `Title`, `IsEnabled`, etc.. but an HTML Widget for example will have a BodyContent field and a Slider Widget would have a collection of images, etc..

My first thought was using `[UIHint]` and `Html.EditorFor` so that each widget type will have its own markup.. I think that's pretty straightforward, but how could we get the properties from any such arbitrary widget into the `AngularJS` model?

**Example Controller**

```
widgetsApp.controller('widgetController', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.emptyGuid = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000';

    $scope.id = $scope.emptyGuid;
    $scope.title = '';
    $scope.order = 0;
    $scope.enabled = false;
    $scope.widgetType = '';
    $scope.zoneId = $scope.emptyGuid;
    // etc
    // how to get properties of ANY widget type?
```

Is this even possible? Is there a better solution? Note, I might consider changing the code to use `Knockout` or some other such framework if it can support my requirements.

**Edit**

Note that the issue is further complicated because of the fact of needing to then pass such a model back to the server and dealing with it there. In regular MVC controllers, I can use `Request.Form` to inspect what other values are there, but I'm using `Web API` and not sure if that's possible there.

**Edit 2**

Okay, so I think I'm on the right track, but still having issues. Firstly, here's my progress:

I found out about `.factory` and made a test page like this:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="controller1">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="showAllInfo()">Show Info</button>
    </div>
    <div ng-controller="controller2">
    </div>
</div>    

<script type="text/javascript">
        var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

        myApp.factory('widgetModel', function () {
            return {
                id: '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000',
                title: '',
                order: 0,
                enabled: false,
                widgetName: '',
                widgetType: '',
                zoneId: '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000',
                displayCondition: '',
                widgetValues: '',
                pageId: null,
                cultureCode: '',
                refId: null,
            };
        });

        // This is representative of the main controller
        myApp.controller('controller1', function ($scope, widgetModel) {
            $scope.emptyGuid = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000';
            $scope.model = widgetModel;
            $scope.model.id = $scope.emptyGuid;

            $scope.showAllInfo = function () {
                alert("id: " + $scope.model.id + ", New Property: " + $scope.model.myNewProperty);
            };
        });

        // This is representative of the details controller (to add properties specific to that particular widget type)
        myApp.controller('controller2', function ($scope, widgetModel) {
            $scope.model = widgetModel;
            $scope.model.myNewProperty = "My Awesome Widget";
        });
    </script>
```

The above test works beautifully.. however, when I use this sort of code in my real application it fails to work and the reason I believe is because the second controller is injected into the DOM later on.. here's what's happening:

I have a `div` as follows

`<div ng-bind-html="widgetDetails"></div>`

and after loading the other details, I load the html for this as such:

```
$http.get("/admin/widgets/get-editor-ui/" + $scope.model.id).success(function (json) {
    $scope.widgetDetails = $sce.trustAsHtml(json.Content);
});
```

That works.. I can see my the html controls for my new properties there.. the following snippet is the HTML which is injected into the above `div`:

```
<div ng-controller="widgetDetailsController">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12">
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.Label("BodyContent", "Body Content", new { @class = "control-label" })
            @Html.TextArea("BodyContent", null, new { @class = "form-control", ng_model = "model.bodyContent", ui_tinymce = "tinyMCEOptions_BodyContent" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <button class="btn" ng-click="test()">Test</button>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    widgetsApp.controller('widgetDetailsController', function ($scope, $http, widgetModel) {
        $scope.model = widgetModel;
        $scope.json = angular.fromJson($scope.model.widgetValues);
        $scope.model.bodyContent = $scope.json.bodyContent || "";

        $scope.test = function () {
            alert($scope.model.bodyContent);
        };
    });
</script>
```

When I click, the "Test" button, nothing happens...

I tried to load a controller dynamically via the method outlined at this link: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2553-loading-angularjs-components-after-your-application-has-been-bootstrapped.htm

It doesn't work. To be honest though, I am new to AngularJS and don't really know all the ins out outs of it.. any help would be great.

Comment: A lot of edits... You may get better answers splitting in two questions.

Comment: The html still contains server side markup. This would not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up changing to KnockoutJS, partly because AngularJS ended up being a bit overkill for my needs, but also because it couldn't handle this situation very nicely (or at least there was no obvious and clean way to do it). My KnockoutJS solution is below:

In the main page, I add an html element:

`<fieldset id="widget-details"></fieldset>`

An example of arbitrary HTML to be injected:

```
<div id="widget-content" class="col-sm-12 col-md-12">
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.Label("BodyContent", "Body Content", new { @class = "control-label" })
        @Html.TextArea("BodyContent", null, new { @class = "form-control", data_bind = "wysiwyg: bodyContent, wysiwygConfig: tinyMCEConfig" })
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function updateModel() {
        var data = ko.mapping.fromJSON(viewModel.widgetValues());

        viewModel.bodyContent = ko.observable("");

        if (data && data.BodyContent) {
            viewModel.bodyContent(data.BodyContent());
        }

        viewModel.tinyMCEConfig = {
            theme: "modern",
            plugins: [
                "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak",
                "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen",
                "insertdatetime media nonbreaking save table contextmenu directionality",
                "emoticons template paste textcolor"
            ],
            toolbar1: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image",
            toolbar2: "print preview media | forecolor backcolor emoticons",
            image_advtab: true,
            templates: [
                { title: 'Test template 1', content: 'Test 1' },
                { title: 'Test template 2', content: 'Test 2' }
            ],
            content_css: tinyMCEContentCss
        };
    };
    function onBeforeSave() {
        var data = {
            BodyContent: viewModel.bodyContent()
        };

        viewModel.widgetValues(ko.mapping.toJSON(data));
    };
</script>
```

Then in my script for the main page, I use the following:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/admin/widgets/get-editor-ui/" + self.id(),
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    async: false
})
.done(function (json) {
    var result = $(json.Content);

    var content = $(result.filter('#widget-content')[0]);
    var details = $('<div>').append(content.clone()).html();
    $("#widget-details").html(details);

    var scripts = result.filter('script');
    scripts.appendTo('body');

    // ensure the function exists before calling it...
    if (typeof updateModel == 'function') {
        updateModel();
        var elementToBind = $("#widget-details")[0];
        ko.cleanNode(elementToBind);
        ko.applyBindings(viewModel, elementToBind);
    }
})
.fail(function () {
    $.notify("There was an error when retrieving the record.", "error");
});
```

and when I save, I call this code:

```
// ensure the function exists before calling it...
if (typeof onBeforeSave == 'function') {
    onBeforeSave();
}
```

Works really well.

Answer (score 0):

IF you are just looking to get the properties and their values, then on AngularJS or Javascript side you can just iterate over the object properties to get all the properties defined over the object.

```
for(var key in obj){
      $scope[key]=obj[key];
 }
```

Once on scope you can bind it to the view using `ng-model`.
This approach would get you the data but metadata about the data such as control to render for property need would not work.

For advance scenarios you should try to send metadata about each properties that can help render it on the view.

If ng-model is setup correctly all data would be send to server.

On the server you can use the dynamic keyword as input parameter to webapi method and there should be a similar method to iterate over the payload using key value pair.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I found what I think is a much cleaner way to do it. However, I am still having problems. Please see my edit above.